# Proper use of class constants in Python

Tags: python, constants

This question specifically relates to the use of the class constants `ABOVE` and `BELOW` in the sample code below.

I have a few different classes in different modules that look like this:

```
class MyClass(object):
    ABOVE = 1
    BELOW = 0

    def __init__(self):
        self.my_numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]

    def find_thing_in_direction(self, direction, cutoff):
        if direction == self.ABOVE:
            return [n for n in self.my_numbers if n > cutoff]
        else:
            return [n for n in self.my_numbers if n < cutoff]


my_class = MyClass()
my_var = my_class.find_thing_in_direction(MyClass.ABOVE, 3)
```

If I have a handful of classes scattered across different modules that each have their own `ABOVE` and `BELOW`, should I extract these constants to somewhere, or is it better to keep the constants within their own classes?

Is there a more Pythonic way to do this instead of using these class constants?

Comment: Moderators: I originally posted this at Code Review, where it was closed as off-topic. I asked in the Programmers SE chat room if it was on-topic for Programmers, and someone suggested it would be better here. If it's not appropriate for stackoverflow, can you please suggest what SE site is best?

Comment: If the value of ABOVE or BELOW were ever to change, would you want all the values to change in concert, or not?

Comment: The `if` block you have there is meaningless, by the way :)

Comment: @unutbu I guess the answer is that if ABOVE or BELOW were to change, I would want the behavior to remain the same. That is, I would expect that if the code were called with direction=ABOVE, the first if statement would execute regardless of the value of ABOVE

Comment: perhaps also `return [n for n in self.my_numbers if (n > cutoff if direction == self.ABOVE else n < cutoff)]` to DRY things up a lil' bit :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you're using classes as namespaces for your constants. You should ask yourself if the `ABOVE` and `BELOW` constants in every single class differs in something between each other.

If a differentiation is required (not just numeric difference, but semantic as well) then storing them in the class they represent is the best approach. On the other side if they have the same semantics in every class then you're not sticking to DRY principle and you're duplicating code.

A solution can be stored them at module level or create a class merely to contain the constants.

Comment: By the way: creating a class to contain constants is **NOT** Pythonic... it's what Java does, because you can't put stuff outside of classes there. In Python, you put it in a module, and if you want to refer to them in a namespaced manner, you import the module, and do `constants.FOO` instead of just `FOO`.

Comment: @ErikAllik I concur with you, if you read carefully that was my first advice, but some people coming from other languages find this hard to understand and also, with some complicated project trees, it can be convenient to do it (in an organizational point of view).

Comment: Just wanted to make sure people were aware of this :)

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

based on the OP's comment, I've realized that I overlooked that fact that `ABOVE` and `BELOW` are not really parametric constants but just strongly typed names (i.e. an enumeration).

Therefore I think the accepted answer is the correct one :)

**Old answer:**

It really boils down to preference if the number of constants is small, in the end, however, if you have a lot of them, namespacing by classes is probably a good idea.

Also, do you have inheritance? if yes, do you override the constant values in subclasses? If yes, you obviously need to keep them inside of your classes.

Also, `my_class.find_thing_in_direction(MyClass.ABOVE, 3)` is smelly: `find_thing_in_direction` should most probably refer to its own class' `ABOVE` constant directly.

Also, `SomeClass` is a really bad class name :)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `find_thing_in_direction` should most probably refer to its own class' `ABOVE` constant directly? Do you mean I should use `self.ABOVE` and not `MyClass.ABOVE`? Also, if I put them in the module, I want to indicate that the user should look at some totally other place in the file for valid values. Is the best way to do this to just write "Pass MyModule.ABOVE or MyModule.BELOW for direction" or do you recommend something else?

Answer (score 0):

For your specific method `find_thing_in_direction`, the `direction` param is better be a `bool` flag named something like `reverse`, just like what the builtin `sorted` function does:

```
def find_thing_in_direction(self, reverse, cutoff):
  if not reverse:
    pass
  else:
    pass
```

This way you don't have to use class attributes.